# Question concerning two sentences

Tags: grammar

What do you think about these two sentences? Are they both correct or is one better than the other?

1. I wish you **tried** to get to grips with the Internet. I'm sure you would enjoy it.
2. I wish you **would try** to get to grips with the Internet. I'm sure you would enjoy it.

Comment: I'd say that strictly speaking #1 is "ungrammatical" in any such construction. Personally I find the *specific* example here rather "awkward" as well as being "relaxed colloquial", but I've no such problem with, for example, *I wish he truly loved me, but I know in my heart he only married me for my money*. Because subtle differences in *exact* context can make a difference (at least to *some* native speakers, such as myself), my advice would be to avoid it in general, and stick to standard "conditional" usages based on auxiliary ***would***, as per your second example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your two example sentences

> I wish you **tried** to get to grips with the Internet.
>   I wish you **would try** to get to grips with the Internet.

mean similar things, that the listener has not learned anything about the internet.

However, the nuance is

> I wish you **tried** to get to grips with the Internet.

may mean the listener may have tried *something else* other than fully understanding the internet, or may mean the listener *did not put any effort* into the internet.

Whereas

> I wish you **would try** to get to grips with the Internet.

may mean the listener *did not consider* fully understanding the internet and you are *urging them to do so*.

As with most examples, additional context will clarify specific meanings.